# How to remove dog slobber from clothing without laundering?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, pets

Most dog owners know the situation: You have *just* changed into freshly laundered clothes and *of course* your pooch runs up or past you, touching your pant leg briefly. And there it is - the dreaded slobber trace.

Of course we could just change again, but is there a simple way to remove the snot-like stain without putting the whole pair of pants in the washing machine? Especially when you notice the spot after leaving home? Wiping at the spot with a dry tissue doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

My **hack** is to

- wear **patterned clothing** such as

[image]

<sup>From [Moss Bros](https://www.mossbros.ie/trousers) (*no affiliation*).</sup>

The idea is that the slobber is not noticeable, the same reasoning as for having patterned carpets in the house.

Comment: I mean...you won't be noticed for slobber at least.

Comment: Works as you get older and start to drool a bit too. ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket you'd need a patterned shirt for that. I stopped at trousers or skirts on the assumption that shirts and tops are above dog-jowl level.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of slobber - wet wipes/baby wipes might work. Some dogs do have *remarkable* levels of slobber and that might need a pressure hose, but for moderate slobber levels, you could just wipe it off.

Answer (score 1):

If you find dried traces of slobber on your clothing, you might be able to brush them off with a (clean) shoe brush, hand brush (the one to clean under your fingernails) or dishwashing brush.

In any case, the brush should have hard bristles to be able to scrape the dried slobber from the textiles. Take care not to damage woolen or knitted textiles.

Answer (score 1):

**How to remove dog slobber from clothing without laundering?**

I would recommend using a damp dish cloth with a drop  of dish washing liquid soup on it. Dish clothes are generally rough enough to do the work.

Wet wipes/baby wipes might work, but I believe the wipes themselves would be too smooth to take off the dog slobber effectively. In an emergency, go for it!